# Can a gen_server receive messages from two different client processes?

Tags: erlang

- I have a `gen_server` (`my_gen_server.erl`) that is started by another server (i.e. `ejabberd`)
- Inside `my_gen_server.erl`, I start another server which handles `HTTP2` calls like this:

  ```
  {ok, ServerPid} = apns:connect(cert, my_first_connection).
  ```
- Now, `my_gen_server` is receiving messages both from `ejabberd` and `ServerPid` which I handle as follows:

  ```
  1. handle_info({reconnecting, ServerPid}=Msg, State) -> %% do Something
  2. handle_info({connection_up, ServerPid}=Msg, State) -> %% do Something

  3. handle_info(#offline_msg{...} = _Msg, State) -> %% do Something
  ```

So 1 & 2 are sent by `ServerPid` and 3 is sent by `ejabberd`. This is working but I am not sure about the correct behavior. So,

My question is:

- Is this correct `gen_server` behavior to receive/handle messages from multiple client processes?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any process that has the gen_server's pid can send the gen_server a message using `!`, which will be handled by the gen_server's function:

```
handl_info()
```

Any process that has the gen_server's pid can call the functions:

```
call(GenServerPid, Msg) 
cast(GenServerPid, Msg)
```

which will be handled by the gen_server functions:

```
handle_call() 
handle_cast()
```

In elixir, there is a module called `Agent`, which is just a gen_server that stores State, like a counter.  Multiple processes can update the counter and retrieve the current count.  Of course, some process has to start the gen_server, then pass the pid to the other processes that want to update/retrieve the count.